# Rest Assured basic auth issue

Tags: rest-assured

I have an endpoint which works perfectly fine when I use Postman with Basic Auth. However, when I tried it in Rest Assured it returns 401. I have tried both different auth methods in rest assured and none of them worked for me so far. Need help!

```
    RequestSpecification requestSpec;
    String baseURI = "http://qa3-phoenix.labcorp.com";
    String basePath = "/phx-rest/healthcheck/ping";
    RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
    RestAssured.baseURI = baseURI;
    requestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
                .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .build();

        Response response = RestAssured
                .given()
                    .spec(requestSpec)
                    .auth().basic("username","password")
                .when()
                    .get(basePath)
                .then()
                    .extract().response();
```

Comment: It also worked with Postman when I have an Authorization header with the value of "Basic" + base64 encoded username:passoword. However, it returns 401 on rest assured.

Comment: What happens when you comment out this line "RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();"?

Comment: Commenting out that line didn't change anything. So if I use .auth().basic("username","password") it returns 401 with a header SMCHALLANGED=YES and if I use .auth().preemptive().basic("username", "password") it returns 403.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of postman where you set Auth credentials?

Comment: I've added the link for the screenshot.
[link](https://pasteboard.co/HtFIYq8.png)

Answer (score 2):

One can use directly the `Authorization` header with base64 encoded username and password and omit the `auth()` part.

Code example:

```
String authBasic = Base64.encode(String.format("%s:%s", username, password));
rest()
    .header("Authorization", String.format("Basic %s", authBasic))
```

Answer (score 0):

`useRelaxedHTTPSValidation()` is a workaround when the server is not using a valid certificate or you bump into `SSLPeerUnverifiedException`. In most of the scenarios this does not happen.

So try removing `useRelaxedHTTPSValidation()`.

Can you also try the below approach:

While creating your `RequestSpecification`, can you add an object of authentication scheme to your RequestSpecification and then use that to create http requests.

```
    RequestSpecBuilder req = new RequestSpecBuilder();
    PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme auth = new PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme();
    auth.setUserName("");
    auth.setPassword("");
    req.setAuth(auth); 
    req.build();
```

May be you can think of creating your RequestSpec from a separate class or package for better re-use.

Let me know if this helps, or the stacktrace.

Comment: Commenting out that line didn't change anything. So if I use .auth().basic("username","password") it returns 401 with a header SMCHALLANGED=YES and if I use .auth().preemptive().basic("username", "password") it returns 403.

Comment: 403 is returned when you don't have the appropriate rights to request for that resource; something like for a resource you need admin rights but you don't have that. Can you just try creating a RequestSpecification as I have mentioned above and let me know the out come.

Comment: I have actually tried auth methods
    RequestSpecBuilder req = new RequestSpecBuilder();
    PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme auth = new PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme();
    auth.setUserName("nagumosd");
    auth.setPassword("phoLC169");
      
    BasicAuthScheme auth2 = new BasicAuthScheme();
    auth2.setUserName("nagumosd");
    auth2.setPassword("phoLC169");
    requestSpec = req
    .setAuth(auth).setBaseUri(baseURI).build();

Comment: I am clueless at this point then. your other tests are running fine ? wanted to know if the issue is with this end point or with the configuration.